# Вывод числа k и слагаемых

Tags: java

Есть задача:
[image: задача]

Вот такой код у меня вышел:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = s.nextLine();
        List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++){
            arr.add(Character.getNumericValue(n.charAt(i)));
        }
        int k;
        if (arr.get(arr.size() - 1) == 0)
            k = 0;
        else
            k = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++){
            if(arr.get(i) == arr.get(i+1)){}
            else k++;
        }
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        System.out.print(arr.get(i) + " ");
        System.out.print(k);
  }
}
```

Не могу понять, где я ошибаюсь.

Input:
4 90 1 2 10 50

Your output:
4 -1 9 0 -1 1 -1 2 -1 1 0 -1 5 0 13

Correct output:
5 50 10 10 10 10

Comment: А что вы вообще сделать пытаетесь? Я например сортировки как минимум не вижу. Я уже молчу про форму вывода и прочее.

Comment: сразу в получении входных данных. Вам нужно считывать числа (напр. с помощью `Scanner.nextInt`), а вы зачем-то пытаетесь каждый символ в строке преобразовать в цифру.